# Do i need use google maps api only to embed litle map with route calculator/display for only one destination?

Tags: html, google-maps

Well i want to upgrade contact page with dynamic map showing location and give oportunity to calculate route for comapny headquatters. Id it necessery for such simple task use Google api? i mean here generating akey etc? Fo i have any other alternatives to google maps?

Answer (score 2):

There's really no reason to mess with the API at all unless you need to customize the appearance or behavior of gmaps. Why not just use an iframe with a url of:

```
http://maps.google.com/?q=[you-url-encoded-address-here]
```

or better yet, set up a textbox and a 'get directions' button to redirect that frame to:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=[their-address]&daddr=[your-address]
```

edit: this works well in modal dialog if you don't want the google logo sticking out like a sore thumb in your pageflow

Answer (score 1):

You could probably embed directly with a specific URL that will configure it to have the destination you want.

By the way, well written answers are much more likely to receive useful responses here.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider http://www.openlayers.org/ as an alternative to google maps.

In fact open layers can be used to add a Google map, or an OpenStreetMap map or a Bing map, etc.